# Effective way to display the data in the chart

Tags: postgresql, d3.js, highcharts, google-visualization

I have an application where some values are stored in DB, e.g. one value per second. It is 604800 values per 7 days and if I want to view this value in graph I need some effective way how to get only e.g. 800 values from DB if I have chart with 800px width.

I use some aggregation logic where mean value is computed for values in 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12 minute interval and then hour and day interval aggregates are computed.

I use PostgreSQL and this aggregations are computed with statement:

```
 "INSERT INTO aggre_table_ ... SELECT sum(...)/count(*) ... WHERE timestamp > ... and timestamp < ..."
```

Is there any better way how to do this or *what is the best way* of data aggregation for later displaying in charts?

Is it better to do this by some trigger or calling stored procedures?

Is there any DB support for aggregations for D3js, Highcharts or Google Charts?

Comment: While this doesn't answer your question, it may be valid to consider using something like a [ChartRangeFilter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#chartrangefilter) for the Google Visualization API, which would allow you to avoid the problem of aggregation by letting your users zoom, pan, and scan the data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to aggregate your data is a large topic that is independent of your technology choices.  It depends largely on how sensitive the data is, what the important indicators of the data are, what the implications of those indicators are, etc.

Is a single out of range point significant? Or are you looking for the overall trend? These are big questions with answers that aren't always easy.

My general suggestion:

- to display a week worth of data, aggregate to hourly averages.
- provide a range around that line indicating the distribution of points around each average
- if something significant happened within that aggregated point, indicate it with a separate marker
- provide drill down capability for each aggregated point to see the full detail charted, if that level of detail is important (chances are, it's not)

Answer (score 0):

In Highcharts (Highstock in the fact) dataGrouping is used for approximation (see [demo](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/data-grouping)).

Also, [here](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/understanding-highstock) you can find more about Highstock.